# PHP DATE_FORMAT issue

Tags: php, date, format

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. This is the code in a nutshell:

```
$query = "SELECT player, SUM(points), SUM(wins), MIN(date) FROM pointentry GROUP BY player ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo $row['MIN(date)'];
```

I'm trying to echo into an HTML page the " MIN(date) " which is working as is, but I can't seem to be able to get it to query the minimum of a date in a column grouped by another variable (column entry) as a different date format.

The dates all all stored in the db as iso 8601. I want them to display in "%M %d, %Y" but every combination of DATE_FORMAT I have used so far has not worked. It is either in iso 8601 format or comes up blank.

I've googled and tried to read up on this for a long time and can't find the answer! any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of `PHP`

```
echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['MIN(date)']));
```

**Edit**

Use `F` for full month name

```
echo date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['MIN(date)']));
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is there a way to output the full month name, and not just the 3 letter abbreviation?

Comment: @user2467517 See edited answer and consider to accept the answer when it solved your problem.